# wiremock java matchingJsonPath with AND/OR condition not working

Tags: jsonpath, wiremock

```json
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }
```

This is my json and I want to match this request json with these condition:

1. batters -> batter -> id is 1001
   AND
2. topping -> id is 5001

What I have tried :

multiple withRequestBody for each like:

```java
    .withRequestBody(matchigJsonPath("$.batters.batter[?(@.id == '1001')]")
    .withRequestBody(matchigJsonPath("$.topping[?(@.id == '5001')]")
```

**And this works**

However what I want is having only one `matchingJsonPath` with AND/OR operator so that I dont need to repeat `withRequestBody`.

I understand I can use `&&` but that will work only when they are under same element , see the
http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ where `$..book[?(@.price==8.99 && @.category=='fiction')]`  would work because `price` and `category` are both under `book`

I am using wiremock 2.33

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `wiremock` supports the [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators).

With [Jayway-JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) you can try the following queries in https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ that would work.

**CONTAINS**

```
$[?(@.batters.batter[*].id contains "1001" && @.topping[*].id contains "5001")]
```

**IN**

```
$[?("1001" in @.batters.batter[*].id && "5001" in @.topping[*].id)]
```

**EMPTY**

```
$[?(@.batters.batter[?(@.id == '1001')] empty false  && @.topping[?(@.id == '5001')] empty false)]
```